# Angular $rootScope.$emit and $on not working on sibling controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to uncheck a checkbox on the right column which has a separate controller, when I make a change in the main controller on the same screen. The two controllers are siblings in ui-router hierarchy.

I'm making the event like this

```
$rootScope.$emit('setReady', 0);
```

This is used in more places in the same controller and I want to invoke the listener every time this is executed.
This is supposed to be invoked by events like a button click and a file upload.

And then I'm listening for the event like this

```
$rootScope.$on('setReady', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.change.ready = data;
});
```

I can get it to work (sort of) but when it works it only invokes once (first time event happens) and then it seems like the $on listener does not listen anymore. After page refresh it would run once again and then stop.
The console.log(data); shows the correct 0 value every time.

It is supposed to toggle this ui element (in this case make it false at every event).

```
<a class="" ng-class="change.ready == 1 ? 'active':''" ui-toggle-class="" >
  <i class="fa fa-square-o text"></i>
  <span class="text">Mark as ready </span>
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o text-active"></i>
  <span class="text-active">Marked as ready </span>
</a>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself, so if anyone runs into similar, then here is the answer.

First of all, the problem doesn't lie directly in the $emit and $on functions but in the values of the $rootScope.

The ui-element takes boolean values `true` and `false`, where as I used the boolean values `1` and `0`, because that's how they are stored in MySQL.

Second, the $scope needs to know about the change before it's sent as a value, and therefore this code is added in my checkbox ng-click function

```
$scope.change.ready = $scope.change.ready == false ? true : false;
```

before the values are sent to backend

```
$scope.change.ready == true ? 1 : 0
```

After that, the functions work when implemented like this

```
$rootScope.$on('setReady', function (event, data) {
    $scope.change.ready = data;
});
```

and

```
$rootScope.$emit('setReady', false);
```

Now everything is emitted fine across sibling controllers.

Comment: an adivse about the mysql thing and other craps that can come from backend. You can chain promise, a good usage of this is to have one .then in your service to format server data properly for your controller that will get them with another .then :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you maybe give a code example of the double .then() chaining, so I know exactly what you mean? I would appreciate that.

Comment: in a service layer you do something like : `return $http.get(..).then(function(response){ var data = response.data; [ process your data]; return data}`. In the controller you do `myService.myMethod().then(function(data){[data already processed and ready to used]});` Note that when you chain promise the 2nd one will have in parameter what is return inside the callback of the first.